# Leaflet osm map and extjs4 portal rendering trouble

Tags: extjs4, leaflet, portlet

I am trying to create a simple portlet with map using extjs 4 and leaflet.
The problem is that map does not appear in my portlet element entirely.
It loads some wrong tiles(256x256) that are out of my portlet. This wrong tiles are on left side higher and right side lower.
Is there any tricks to fix it? 
Here on screenshot how it look likes. 
[image: problem with tiles]

Maybe this can help to find out?
I think it happens because of wrong `left` and `top` attributes in img class:

```
<img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" src="http://myhost/map/14/9904/5121/" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: -79px; top: -251px;">
<img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" src="http://myhost/map/14/9905/5123/" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: 177px; top: 261px;">
<img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" src="http://myhost/map/14/9904/5122/" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: -79px; top: 5px;">
<img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" src="http://myhost/map/14/9903/5121/" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: -335px; top: -251px;">
<img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" src="http://myhost/map/14/9902/5121/" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: -591px; top: -251px;">
<img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" src="http://myhost/map/14/9902/5120/" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: -591px; top: -507px;">
<img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" src="http://myhost/map/14/9901/5120/" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: -847px; top: -507px;">
<img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" src="http://myhost/map/14/9901/5119/" style="height: 256px; width: 256px; left: -847px; top: -763px;">
```

Comment: And by the way. 
If i move browser window to another monitor it begins to work correctly.

Comment: And when i change the browser's window size it also begins to work correctly. 
So probably the question is how to force refresh size of browser's window?

Comment: L.map listens to window resize and internally calls `invalidateSize`. So if resizing the browser window restores the correct behaviour, iH8's guess is probably right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to call `L.Map`'s `invalidateSize` method after your panel is fully rendered:

> Checks if the map container size changed and updates the map if so — call it after you've changed the map size dynamically, also animating pan by default.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-invalidatesize

I'm no ExtJS specialist but i took a quick glance at the API and it seems to me you can do that by listening for the `afterRender` event whichs is fired on `Ext.panel.Panel`:

> Fires after the component rendering is finished.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-event-afterrender

EDIT: Found this example where they initialize a Google Map in a afterRender function of `Ext.panel.Panel`. This is done for the same reason: At that point the panel's size can be determined which is a necessity for correctly initializing the map instance:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/example/window/gmap.html

EDIT 2: Since OP said none off the above is a solution i modified the google example to use Leaflet and created a testcase on Plunker:

http://embed.plnkr.co/Fo9nOYH3KUHRqw4Soq6F/

Comment: I'de take a second look if i was you. What you are describing is a classic sign of the `L.Map` instance not being able to correctly determine it's dimensions. This is solved by either initializing when the container is fully rendered or by calling `invalidateSize` when the container is fully rendered.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it tommorow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Method  invalidateSize() solve my problem. I put it on map resize event.